# PySide2 in Maya - 'module' object has no attribute 'QPushButton'

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, maya

guys!
Trying to learn so PySide for Maya 2017 and from first step it was already a bit frustrating.

```
from PySide2 import QtGui

button = QtGui.QPushButton()
```

- 'module' object has no attribute 'QPushButton'
  Anybody knows something about it ?

Comment: In PySide2 QPushButton is part of QtWidgets:  `from PySide2 import QtWidgets

button = QtWidgets.QPushButton()`. PySide is a wrapper of Qt4, whereas PySide2 is of Qt5, and Qt5 reorganized the classes for various reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this method:

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import * 

button = QPushButton("Hello World") 
button.show()
```

[image]

Comment: QPushButton belongs to QtWidgets.

Answer (score 0):

button = QtWidgets.QPushButton()